# OR query with Tire / Elastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

This is probably very simple, but I can't work it out. I have this tire/elasicsearch query on Project class:

```
  def self.search(params)
    tire.search(load: true, page: params[:page], per_page: 8) do
      query do
        boolean do
          must { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:query].present?
          must { term :status, "posted" }
          must { term :budget, params[:budget] } if params[:budget].present?
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

I need the Status term to be searching on 'posted' OR 'closed' and can't work this out. I tried term :status, ["posted", "closed"]  but this doesn't return results so probably doing an AND.
Be grateful for the right tire syntax here. (NB not looking for the jason/elasticsearch string here)
Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is a [`terms`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/terms-query.html) query, which does the `OR` between terms passed as an array:

```
must { terms :status, ["posted"] }
```

or something like this for dynamic values:

```
# params[:status] can be single value or array
must { terms :status, Array(params[:status]) }
```

See [this part of Tire documentation](http://karmi.github.com/tire/#section-70) for more info and context.

Comment: Thanks, hadn't spotted difference between term vs termS is the docs